# Application which is running on RedHat 7.5 connect to SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, linux, kerberos

We are deploying a java application to RHEL 7.5, this java application need connect to SQL Server 2016. As security request, we must use integrated security to connect SQL Server 2016. Follow Microsoft website's suggestion, we are implementing Kerberos in Windows AD Server and RHEL 7.5.

Unfortunately, we are facing a credentials issue. klist command is working fine on RHEL 7.5, means Kerberos clinet which has installed in RHEL7.5 can talk to Kerberos Server(Windows AD server) as normal. And RHEL7.5 can ping / talnet AD Server and SQL Server.

we have followed Microsoft's spec to set SPN as following:

```
setspn -A HTTP/SERVER_01.devdc.local@DEVDC.LOCAL devdc.local\admin.
```

As microsoft's guideline, we should use  MSSQLSvc not HTTP, but it has issue when we use MSSQLSvc, we think the reason is OS version of AD server is Windows Server 2012, so cannot support MSSQLSvc protocal.  After change to HTTP, kerberos is working fine. Can use kinit generate ticket and use klist to see the ticket information.

Part of our Java code as below:

```
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "~/krb5.conf"); 
SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource(); 
ds.setServerName("192.168.100.150"); 
ds.setPortNumber(1234); 
ds.setIntegratedSecurity(true); 
ds.setAuthenticationScheme("JavaKerberos"); 
ds.setDatabaseName("DB_TEST");
```

The error details as following:

*Error connection to database:(using class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver)
GSSException: No valid credentials provide (mechanism level: Server not found)
KrbException: Server not found in Kerberos database(7)
KrbException: Identifier doesn't match expected value(906)*

I would be grateful if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be setting the SPN.  See

> A service principal name (SPN) is the name by which a client uniquely
>   identifies an instance of a service.
>
> You can specify the SPN using the serverSpn connection property, or
>   simply let the driver build it for you (the default). This property is
>   in the form of: "MSSQLSvc/fqdn:port@REALM" where fqdn is the
>   fully-qualified domain name, port is the port number, and REALM is the
>   Kerberos realm of the SQL Server in upper-case letters. The realm
>   portion of this property is optional if your Kerberos configuration's
>   default realm is the same realm as that of the Server and is not
>   included by default. If you wish to support a cross-realm
>   authentication scenario where the default realm in the Kerberos
>   configuration is different than the realm of the Server, then you must
>   set the SPN with the serverSpn property.
>
> For example, your SPN might look like:
>   "MSSQLSvc/some-server.zzz.corp.contoso.com:1433@ZZZZ.CORP.CONTOSO.COM"

[Using Kerberos integrated authentication to connect to SQL Server - Service principal names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-kerberos-integrated-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#service-principal-names).

The driver will attempt to build the SPN for you from the other connection attributes, but you've got an IP address instead of a FQDN, so it cannot build the correct SPN.  In the default configuration SQL Server registers its own SPNs and you can see the correct SPN in the SQL Server log, but there are scenarios where additional SPNs must be registered for the service account, and you would need to use the `setspn` command on Windows to see them.

Assuming your SQL Server is listening on port 1234, and you haven't changed the service account for the SQL Server instance from the default, then the SPNs should be registered for the machine accoune, and the `setspn` statements should be:

```
setspn –A MSSQLSvc/SERVER_01.devdc.local devdc\SERVER_01$
setspn –A MSSQLSvc/SERVER_01.devdc.local:1234 devdc\SERVER_01$
```

if you've set a domain account as the service account, say `devdc\sqlsvc` then substitute that.

```
setspn –A MSSQLSvc/SERVER_01.devdc.local devdc\sqlsvc
setspn –A MSSQLSvc/SERVER_01.devdc.local:1234 devdc\sqlsvc
```

**TL/DR use the SQL Server's fully-qualified domain name (FQDN) for setServerName() instead of an IP address.  If that doesn't work, you'll have to ask your network security people what SPNs are registered for the SQL Server service account.  If you give up on Kerberos, fall back to NTLM.**

Also in the newer JDBC driver Microsoft has implemented NTLM, which is the *other* Windows Authentication protocol.

But be aware of the following security caveat:

> The NTLM protocol is an old authentication protocol with various
>   vulnerabilities, which pose a security risk. It's based on a
>   relatively weak cryptographic scheme and is vulnerable to various
>   attacks. It's replaced with Kerberos, which is a lot more secure and
>   recommended. **NTLM authentication should only be used in a secure
>   trusted environment, or when Kerberos can't be used.**
>
> The Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server only supports NTLM v2, which
>   has some security improvements over the original v1 protocol. It's
>   also recommended to enable Extended Protection, or use SSL Encryption
>   for increased security.

[Using NTLM Authentication to connect to SQL Server - Security risks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-ntlm-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#security-risks)

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your reply. yup, we have set SPN on AD Server , the command is as following: 
setspn -A HTTP/SERVER_01.devdc.local@DEVDC.LOCAL devdc.local\admin. As microsoft's spec, we should use  MSSQLSvc not HTTP, but have issue when we use MSSQLSvc, we think the reason is OS version of AD server is Windows Server 2012, so cannot support MSSQLSvc protocal

Comment: The OS version is not an issue.  Kerb troubleshooting is so common we released a tool to help. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2985455/kerberos-configuration-manager-for-sql-server-is-available  And again, SQL Server should have already registered the SPN as the SQL Error Log will show.

Comment: Hi David,
Checked your updated setspn statement. I have two questions need to verify with you
1. For my understanding, we only need to run this setspn on AD server, no need to run it on SQL Server, is it correct ? 
2. And because we tried use MSSQLSvc then got issue, so change to HTTP, or must use MSSQLSvc to register this protocol ?

Comment: Yes you can run it on any domain server, and yes it must be for MSSQLSvc.

Comment: Hi David,
Sure, I will try it now. Look like we are used incorrect command before: 
setspn -A HTTP/SERVER_01.devdc.local@DEVDC.LOCAL devdc.local\admin

Comment: Hi David, after set spn, when generate keytype, , the command as below :
ktpass /out c:\kerberos\kerberos.keytab /princ MSSQLSvc/SERVER_01.devdc.local:1234 /mapuser admin@devdc.local /crypto AES256-SHA1 /ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL /pass xxxxxx
is it correct ?

Comment: Hi David, 
I followed your instruction to do it. Now error message become as following:
KDCRep: init() encoding tag is 126 req type is 13
>>>KRBError: 
  suSec is 995763
  error code is 14
  error Message is KDC has no support for encryption type
  sname is MSSQLSvc/sqlserver.devdc.local:1234@DEVDC.LOCAL
  msgType is 30

Comment: I don't know.  You may be better off over at http://serverfault.com at this point.

Comment: Sure, David, Thank you so much.